# VBA Searches for folder names and creates a list of folder paths

Tags: vba

I'm using this code, but I'm trying to change it to get a list of folder paths. The code looks in the directory for the name of the folder of the entered text in cells C and D, but there is no cyclicity when returning the result.

```vb
Sub GetPath()

    Dim searchFolderName As String
    
    searchFolderName = "D:\"
    
    Dim FileSystem As Object

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   doFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(searchFolderName)

End Sub

Sub doFolder(folder)
    Dim subFolder
    Dim myLastRow As Long, myRow As Long
    myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For myRow = 3 To myLastRow
    If Cells(myRow, "C") = "" Then
            On Error Resume Next
              End If
              FolderName = "P_BNB_" & Cells(myRow, "C") & "_" & Cells(myRow, "D")
    For Each subFolder In folder.subfolders
        If Split(subFolder, "\")(UBound(Split(subFolder, "\"))) = FolderName Then
            Sheets("Create Folders").Cells(myRow, "E") = subFolder
             
        End
        End If

        doFolder subFolder
    Next subFolder
Next myRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next` - does anything change?

Comment: You recursion is not set up correctly  - every time it calls itself it repeats the loop over the rows: that row looping needs to be somewhere else.